# Indeterminate forms other than the 7 common ones

Tags: limits, indeterminate-forms

The following 7 indeterminate forms are all I can find in any calculus books:
$$\frac{0}{0}, \frac{\infty}{\infty}, 0 \cdot \infty, \infty - \infty, 0^0, \infty^0, 1^\infty.$$

For example, by $\frac{0}{0}$, I am referring to the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ with $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x) = 0$. Also, $1^\infty$ is understood to include the case $1^{-\infty}$, just as $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ is understood to include $-\infty$ in the numerator/denominator. Finally, the function in the base of $0^0$ is understood to be approaching $0$ from the right.

In contrast, here are some forms which are not indeterminate forms:
$$0^{\pm\infty}, \infty^{\pm\infty}, \frac{0}{\pm\infty}, \frac{\pm\infty}{0^+}, \frac{\pm\infty}{0^-}.$$

Then I came across this post: [Are $\log_1 1$ and $\log_0 0$ indeterminate forms?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3079722)

I think the forms $\log_1 1$ and $\log_{0^+} {0^+}$ are also indeterminate forms, and they can respectively be transformed into the types $\frac{0}{0}$ and $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ using $\log_{f(x)} [g(x)] = \frac{\ln g(x)}{\ln f(x)}$.

Can you list some other indeterminate forms?